# List formation in output with one database column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running into a scenario that I am not sure what the best approach is or if there is a solution to what I am facing. I created a simple database table to house job postings. There is a table column called job requirements. The text that goes with this column should be in list format. Is there anyway, whether it is on the database end or via php, to get the data to populate as a list without having to code it into the database using `<li></li>` or without having to have numerous columns for different list points?

The data in the database is in text format not with breaks where new bullets should start.

I am outputting it with the `echo '<ul class="jobRequirementList"><li>'. $job_requirements .'</li></ul>';` and getting the data with a foreach loop.

Does anyone see what I could do?

[image]

My php code:

```
foreach ($career_rows as $career_row) {
        $category = $career_row['category'];
        $job_title = $career_row['job_title'];
        $job_description = $career_row['job_description'];
        $job_requirements = $career_row['job_requirements'];
        $job_status = $career_row['active'];                
            $AtLeastOneCareer = true;
            echo '<div class="posting">';
                echo '<div class="postingInner">';
                    echo '<span class="postingCategory hGc">'. $category .'</span>';
                    echo '<h3 class="postingTitle">'. $job_title .'</h3>';
                    echo '<p class="postingDescription dGsmall">'. $job_description .'</p>';
                    echo '<ul class="jobRequirementList"><li>'. $job_requirements .'</li></ul>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: What does your job_requirements data look like?  How are you delimiting the requirements?  You indicate they are **not** separated by breaks.

Comment: @Sentinel I just added a picture for you to see what the data looks like.

Comment: If you store job_requirements list in one text column in DB with some separator string or your choice, for example '@@@', you can use code like this in php: `join('</li><li>',preg_split('/@@@/',$job_requirements))`, possibly wrapping it into htmlspecialchars((). Not sure this is any better than explicitely storing `</li><li>` in DB though.

Comment: @YuriLachin This works perfectly. For some reason wrapping in `htmlspecialchars` breaks the output and nothing displays for one of the records. This is one that actually should need it because it has "3-5 years". Any ideas why it would do this?

Comment: Hard to tell without code and data sample. Hope you put wrap in the right place? `htmlspecialchars($job_requirements)` suggested to escape occasional html code inside $job_requirements. Alsom htmlspecialchars() is not a bullet-proof solution you can find motrereliable ways in comments to `htmlspecialchars` docs on php site or google for alternatives.

Comment: @YuriLachin Yes, like this: `,preg_split('/@@@/',htmlspecialchars($job_requirements)))` I also tried wrapping the split as well. The first output loop disappears, while the others remain in tact.

Comment: There is nothing special for html markup or php in `"3-5 years"` string. It's smth else in you $job_requirements string that is causing trouble. Or it might be smth in "jobRequirementList" css class.